# GpuRaySensor.hh missing in 1.3?

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like GpuRaySensor.hh went missing in Gazebo 1.3. I checked out the lastest source from the repo:

```
~/src/gazebo$ ls gazebo/sensors/Gpu*
gazebo/sensors/GpuRaySensor.cc  gazebo/sensors/GpuRaySensor.hh
```

But in my installed (Ubuntu package), there is no more GpuRaySensor:

```
/usr/include/gazebo-1.3$ ls gazebo/sensors/Gpu*
ls: cannot access gazebo/sensors/Gpu*: No such file or directory
```

Pretty sure it was there in 1.2 and earlier as I had compiled worked on an extension to the base GpuRaySensor class.

### Update

Because I am impatient, I tried pulling in the relevant sources into my sensor that were missing from installed Gazebo 1.3 (GpuRaySensor.hh/.cc, GpuLaser.hh/.cc). But then ran into the following compile error:

```
In file included from .../plugins/src/GpuLaser.cc:27:0:
/usr/include/gazebo-1.3/gazebo/rendering/ogre_gazebo.h:22:18: fatal error: Ogre.h: No such file or directory
```

Looks like Ogre.h is in,

```
/usr/include/OGRE
```

Not in,

```
/usr/include
```

Ultimately is this why GpuLaser didn't make it into 1.3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/493/gpuraysensor.hh-missing-in-1.3?/) by [yamokosk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/69/yamokosk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's a [gpu_sensors](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/7e8e590dfc2a881834d47b04361862b5b22f34d2/?at=gpu_sensors) branch that should at least compile for you.

Opened an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/300/gpulaser-and-gpuraysensor-missing-in-13) and a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/188/missing-gpu-laser-ray-sensor-in-13-issue/diff).

It was not merged because we didn't get a chance to remove `rendering::GpuLaser` dependency on `sensors::GpuRaySensor`.  Work in progress (see the pull request above).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1